# Como saber a cual grupo pertenece un usuario

Tags: python, django

Buenos dias estoy desarrollando una aplicacion la cual permite llevar un control sobre los usuarios que pertenecen a un cierto grupo, pero me estoy encontrando con un problema el cual no se como llevar de la forma correcta, actualmente tengo dos grupos los cuales son diurno y nocturno, pero tengo un inconveniente, y es que esos grupos son validados en una vista para saber a cual pertenece, pero que pasaria si quiero agregar mas grupos de los cuales tengo, hay alguna forma de saber a cual grupo pertenece y de esa manera poder validar, este es mi modelo:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    group = models.ManyToManyField(Group, related_name='group')

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def group_user(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    if instance.group:
        if instance.group == 'diurno':
            group = Group.objects.get(name='diurno')
            instance.groups.clear()
            instance.groups.add(group)
        else:
            group = Group.objects.get(name='nocturno')
            instance.groups.clear()
            instance.groups.add(group)
```

Esta es mi vista:

```
class CarListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    login_url = 'users:login'
    template_name = 'index.html'
    paginate_by = 6

    def get_queryset(self):
        group = self.request.user.groups.filter(
            name='diurno').exists()
        if group:
            return Car.objects.annotate(Count('partner')).order_by('-pk')
        else:
            user = User.objects.filter(pk=self.request.user.pk).first()
            return Car.objects.filter(user=user)
```

Comment: Los grupos deberían estar guardados en una tabla, así la app funcionaría bien si agregas 1 o mas grupos sin agregar los `if`.

Comment: los if son para validar a cual grupo pertenece

Comment: Claro, me imagino que el usuario tiene un id de grupo (Ej: 1), ese código va a estar en la tabla de grupos y con ese id validarías.

Comment: pero si lo hago de esa manera no hay forma de saber a que grupo pertenece el usuario de forma dinamica, porque de esa manera puedo saber de forma facil con dos grupos, pero en caso de que quiera agregar mas grupos, y segun el grupo asi mismo muestre la informacion en el template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para obtener a que grupos pertenece un usuario se hace de esta manera:

```
print('grupos:', self.request.user.groups.all())
```

Esta instrucción te devuelve un queryset con todos los grupos a los que pertenece el usuario.

Si quieres ver si el usuario esta en un grupo determinado:

```
if request.user.groups.filter(name__in=['diurno']):
    print('usuario pertenece a grupo diurno')
```

Si quieres ver si esta en varios grupos:

```
if request.user.groups.filter(name__in=['diurno', 'nocturno]):
    print('usuario esta en uno y otro o ambos grupos)
```

Estas instrucciones te dan como resultado un queryset vacío si el usuario no pertenece, y en caso de que este en el grupo con alguno de los nombres de la lista te devuelve un queryset con el o los grupos.

EDITO: Como te comentaba puedes verificar el grupo usando un decorador al inicio de tu view, te adjunto un ejemplo simple para verificar el grupo, lo puedes modificar a tus necesidades.

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import user_passes_test


def group_required(*group_names):
    """ Grupos, checar si pertenece a grupo """

    def check(user):
        if user.groups.filter(name__in=group_names).exists() | user.is_superuser:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    # Si no se pertenece al grupo, redirigir a /prohibido/
    return user_passes_test(check, login_url='/prohibido/')
```

Para usar el decorador:

```
@group_required('diurno')
def view_protegida(request):
   return render(request, 'archivo.html',
                  {'valido': True})
```

Con el ejemplo anterior no te dejara acceder al view si no perteneces al grupo 'diurno'.

Por ultimo, puedes implementar una funcion que puedas llamar donde quieras, un ejemplo simple:

```
def pertenece_cualquier_grupo(usuario, lista_grupos):
    return True if usuario.groups.filter(name__in=lista_grupos) else False
```

Como llamarla:

```
def view_ejemplo(request):
   if pertenece_cualquier_grupo(request.user, ['diurno']):
      # Hacer algo
       return render(request, 'archivo.html',
                      {'valido': True})
```

Comment: si ese codigo tambien lo he intentado, pero el problema que tengo es que pasaria si quiero agregar mas grupos y validar si un usuario pertenece a ese grupo, es decir empece con 2 grupos y quiero agregar otros dos, tengo que repetir ese codigo cada vez que agrege otro grupo?

Comment: Podrías repetir el código cada vez, o crear una función que te pida de parámetro, hacer una acción y retornar un valor, así en lugar de repetir todo el código podrías solo incluir la función. Otra opción es usar un decorador al inicio de tu función. Te agrego al post un ejemplo de decorador para verificar el grupo.

Comment: bien muchas gracias ya pude revisar mejor y entender